# Automapping child injecting data

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm trying to map a parent/child to another parent/child where the child.id need to be read from a key/value dictionary.

I could do a foreach loop to map the children but I'm interrested to see if there is another way. The code is a simplified version of my model and the remoteDict is read async so using a `IValueResolver` seems unusable?

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<ParentFrom, ParentTo>()
                    .ForMember(d => d.Children, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Children));
                cfg.CreateMap<(ChildFrom child, Dictionary<string, int> dict), ChildTo>()
                    .ForMember(d => d.Id, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.dict.GetValueOrDefault(s.child.ExternalId)));
            });
            var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

            Dictionary<string, int> remoteDict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            remoteDict.Add("A1", 1);
            remoteDict.Add("B1", 1);

            ParentFrom p = new ParentFrom() { Id = 1001 };
            p.Children.Add(new ChildFrom() { ExternalId = "A1" });
            p.Children.Add(new ChildFrom() { ExternalId = "B1" });

            ParentTo p2 = mapper.Map<ParentTo>(p);
            /*
                Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
                Mapping types:
                    ChildFrom -> ChildTo
                    mapping.ChildFrom -> mapping.ChildTo
            */
        }
    }

    public class ParentFrom
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public List<ChildFrom> Children { get; set; } = new List<ChildFrom>();
    }

    public class ChildFrom
    {
        public string ExternalId { get; set; }
    }

    public class ParentTo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public List<ChildTo> Children { get; set; }
    }

    public class ChildTo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
```

UPDATE

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<ParentFrom, ParentTo>()
                    .ForMember(d => d.Children, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Children));
                cfg.CreateMap<ChildFrom, ChildTo>()
                    .ForMember(d => d.Id, o => o.MapFrom<FromRemote>());
            });
            var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

            Dictionary<string, int> remoteDict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            remoteDict.Add("A1", 1);
            remoteDict.Add("B1", 1);

            ParentFrom p = new ParentFrom() { Id = 1001 };
            p.Children.Add(new ChildFrom() { ExternalId = "A1" });
            p.Children.Add(new ChildFrom() { ExternalId = "B1" });

            ParentTo p2 = mapper.Map<ParentTo>(p, opt => opt.Items["dict"] = remoteDict);
        }
    }

    public class FromRemote : IValueResolver<ChildFrom, ChildTo, int>
    {
        public int Resolve(ChildFrom source, ChildTo destination, int destMember, ResolutionContext context)
        {
            var dict = context.Items["dict"] as Dictionary<string, int>;
            return dict.GetValueOrDefault(source.ExternalId);
        }
    }

    public class ParentFrom
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public List<ChildFrom> Children { get; set; } = new List<ChildFrom>();
    }

    public class ChildFrom
    {
        public string ExternalId { get; set; }
    }

    public class ParentTo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public List<ChildTo> Children { get; set; }
    }

    public class ChildTo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Custom-value-resolvers.html#passing-in-key-value-to-mapper

Comment: Yes, got it thanks.